# Eдиничное нажатие на клавишу

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть Пианино в котором при нажатии на кнопку воспроизводится определенный звук.
Как сделать так что бы при нажатии и удержании на клавишу, `button1.PerformClick();` срабатывал 1 раз и звук не повторялся.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.D1:
            button1.PerformClick();
            button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            label3.Text = "До / 1";
            label5.Text = "1";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Храните в классе переменную `bool isPressed`. В методе `Form1_KeyDown` устанавливайте её в `true`, в методе `Form1_KeyUp` - в `false`. Проверяйте, не нажата ли сейчас кнопка в методе `Form1_KeyDown` через `if(!isPressed){...}`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать отключить автоповтор в настройках клавиатуры.

Или решить на программном уровне, выставлять флаг нажатия, и если он выставлен, игнорировать KeyDown нажатой клавиши, пока не произойдёт её KeyUp. Правда, есть опасность, что отпускание будет потеряно - у клавиатур есть ограничение на количество одновременно нажатых клавиш, при превышении которого следующие события игнорируются. Да и по другим причинам событие может потеряться.